# Why does my value of image variable change?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing

I don't know what happened with my variable. When the variable "amarilloSegm" is inside in the method "Suma_Manchas(amarilloSegm, NecrosadoSegm) it change its value. The strange is that my variable is not modify in all the method.

This is my code, when I call the method:

```
...
imgManchasUnidas = Suma_Manchas(amarilloSegm, necrosadoSegm)
...
```

And this is my body of method:

```
def Suma_Manchas(imagen_1, imagen_2):
    imgAma = imagen_1
    imgNecro = imagen_2
    manchasUnidas = imgAma  

    y, x = manchasUnidas.shape

    for fil in range (0, y):
        for col in range (0, x):
#           print "x: " + str(fil) + " y: " + str(col)
            valUmbral = imgNecro[fil, col]
            if (valUmbral > BLANCO-20):
                manchasUnidas.itemset((fil, col), BLANCO)

    return manchasUnidas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do `imgAma = imagen_1` and then, `manchasUnidas = imgAma`, and finally modify `manchasUnidas`, which ends up modifying `imagen_1`, since it copies the references instead of creating a new object in the memory.

You can do [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) if you want have a brand new object in another part of the memory, so that when you change one, the other one will not be modified.

More specifically:

```
import copy
def Suma_Manchas(imagen_1, imagen_2):
    imgAma = copy.deepcopy(imagen_1)
    ...
```